# Magento 2 - Load data from store instead of hardcoding

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs, script

I am creating a new tag programmatically and append it to the DOM.

Currently I hardcoded the phone number, because I don't know exactly how I can load it from the store by using javascript.

This is my code:

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "domReady!"
], function($) {

    // ToDo: Programmatically add phone number to header
    // currently hardcoded
    jQuery('<li>', {
        id: 'header_phone',
        class: 'ammenu-item category-item -main -full nav-7',
    }).appendTo('.ammenu-main-container .ammenu-items');

    jQuery('<a>', {
        id: 'header_phone_link',
        class: 'ammenu-link -main -parent',
        title: 'Tel.: [09xxx] xxxxx - 0',
        href: 'tel:+49xxxxxxxxxx',
        html: 'Tel.: [09xxx] xxxxx - 0'
    }).appendTo('#header_phone');
});

</script>
```

This script is injected to every site.

How can I load the real values from the store instead of hardcoding them?

Thx